# AspNetCore - change cookie name when using Google Authentication

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-core

In ASP.NET 5, MVC 6, I was able to change the name of the external authentication cookie in the options - but that seems to be removed from the new providers in `AspNetCore.Identity` `RC2` libraries.

I've got this setup;

```
class Startup {
   ...
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){
      services.AddIdentity<Member, Role> ... // identity wired up
   }

   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ILoggerFactory logger) {
      // .. other wiring
    app
        .UseIdentity()
        .UseGoogleAuthentication
        (new GoogleOptions {
            ClientId = Constants.Google.Client,
            ClientSecret = Constants.Google.Secret,
            Scope = {"email", "profile"}
        });

    app.UseMvc(routes => {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
         });
    }
}
```

There used to be an `AuthenticationType` property that I could set to a `string` and it would control the cookie name; But that's gone.

I read other posts that said to try `SignInScheme` and `AuthenticationScheme` - and I did, but that would start giving me an error that there was `No Provider to Handle this Scheme`.

Is there anything I can do for it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's how you can replace the default name used for the external cookie.

```
services.AddIdentity<Member, Role>(options =>
{
    options.Cookies.ExternalCookie.CookieName = "name";
});
```

Comment: You are a god among insects.

Answer (score 6):

It's work for me in VS2017

In the Startup.cs ConfigureServices():

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => {
  options.Cookie.Name = "NewCookieName";
});
```

Comment: Works for me in ASP.NET Core 2.2

Answer (score 5):

ASP.NET Core 2.2

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.Name = "my_cookie";
    });
```